# Why is the color style for the body tag overriding the color style for my class?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the font-size and color of a table cell, but it's not working. I've definined the new font-size and color in a class that I've applied to the table cell, but the color isn't being applied. Here's the CSS I'm using:

```
body {
    background-image:url('../img/gradient.png');
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-color:#E3F2FF;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#00253F;
    }
# The class for my table cell.
.red {
    color::#EC2127;
    font-size:15px;
    }
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<td class="red">Foo</td>
```

In my browser, I see the correct font size, but the color for the body tag is overriding the color assigned to the class for some reason. What am I missing?

Comment: Why are the other "red items" not in the "red" class?

Comment: Can be put on hold: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you have an extra semi colon
    color::#EC2127;

that is probably making it skip the color.  take that out and try it

Comment: I can't count the number of hairs I have lost because of an extra character.  I've learned when my css is being wonky to run it through a css validator and often it will catch things like that.